# Prickling sensation in feet while near electric cables - should I worry about this?

Tags: power

I noticed that I have a prickling sensation in one of my feet near one of my power cables. This doesn't seems to happen next to other cables.

If it matters: 2 computer and 2 screens take their power from that cable.

Should I worry about this or brush it of as maybe sitting in the wrong way?

Comment: @jsotola its bad english while being overtired. Meant foot, my apologise.

Comment: examine the cable very carefully

Comment: Surface cuts and/or moist  dirty insulation will expose that to socks Not good.

Comment: I wonder if [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/216967/38098) discusses the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: use a different chair to see if it may be a problem caused by a pinched nerve

Comment: This is how you learn the Texas Two-Step. On a more serious note I would have this checked out by a doctor first, as tingling is often related to a nerve pinch as @jsotola mentioned.

Comment: @jsotola just to let you know...you where right. Got a new chair and it stopped all of the sudden. If you turn it into an answer I'd mark it. But I think the question will be deleted soon anyway.

Comment: you could delete the question yourself .... it is not related to electronic design anyway .... it is related to electro-chemical data transmission (neural activity) ....... good luck

Comment: @jsotola I can't. Because there are already answers here.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to define "near" and consider the surface you are standing on. The issue is that many devices that use what are called "Switch Mode Power Supplies" (SMPS) can produce what is called Common Mode Noise, a type of electrical interference that is referenced to ground (earth). In a good quality product, this is taken care of with proper grounding and shielding of conductors and / or filtering. it could be however that you have a combination of issues taking place and something is NOT properly taking that noise to ground, so it is "leaking" all over the place. Then combine that with dust, dirt and or moisture in the environment collecting on your cables, and a slightly conductive floor material, it is entirely possible that you might be able to perceive it as that "tingle", akin to feeling the "zap" from static build-up when you walk across certain floors.

The first thing I would be concerned about with this is that the grounding for your equipment in failing / broken / missing. That can have other serious consequences.

Answer (score 0):

What you feel as a tingle, through dry feet implies a non-trivial voltage. "Tingling" in my experience means something close to a milliAmp is flowing.  Can you actually measure a voltage on or across your foot? Anyway, it should not happen so there probably is something to worry about.

Comment: I don't have any instruments to measure this. But by putting my hand on the cable (just putting it with the back side of the hand on the cable, not grabbing) I don't feel anything. I'm just rather confused than worried right now.

Comment: It would require photos closeup and verifying your earth ground connections in each cable.