# How do I find out whether my switched-mode power supply is galvanically separated from mains?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

This question is a follow-up to [Does switched-mode power supply feature galvanic separation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15080/does-switched-mode-power-supply-feature-galvanic-separation) : Over there, stevenvh says:

> "... a mains connected SMPS, and most of those do have galvanic separation."

How do I find out whether a given SMPS (say, my cell phone charger or a similar device, so something without a datasheet readily available) features galvanic isolation?

- If there is no third (earth) connection on the mains plug, is that enough to conclude that the DC output is separated from mains, i.e. do regulations like CE require isolation for non-earthed devices?
- If that's not enough - is it sufficient to test both plaugs on the AC side against both contacts at the DC side with a multimeter, or are there designs that are not separated despite having no connection when turned off?

Answer (score 5):

With a multimeter.  Measure the resistance between various "output" pins and the "input" pins.

A very high resistance (>1 meg ohm) or an open circuit means that it is isolated.  A resistance of less than 10K ohms indicates that it is not isolated.  A resistance in between those two values means that something is weird.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to be sure you need to do Hi pot testing: -

[image]

[Here](http://www.xppower.com/pdfs/High-Pot_Testing.pdf) is a great document from XP that explains it. Class II is what you are looking for i.e. no earth connection. You cannot check that you have galvanic isolation with a multimeter and realistically hope to believe it although you can definitely disprove galvanic isolation if you find some degree of conductivity.

Comment: You cannot verify that the supply meets regulatory safety requirements with a multimeter.  But you can certainly see if the supply is isolated.

Comment: @DavidKessner If it were the audio power output on a PA feeding several distributed loudspeakers I agree that the multimeter test is sufficient to prove the PA uses an output transformer but not on a SMPS. I guess I'm saying that galvanic isolation doesn't necessarily mean safe.

Comment: You're right that Galvanic isolation does not mean safe.  But assuming that the power supply was designed correctly and passes the appropriate regulatory tests (which would be the case with a commercially bought supply) then a multimeter test should correctly indicate if it is isolated or not.  As would reading the datasheets, if available.  To be absolutely sure, you need to do a Hipot testing, as you mentioned, but few people on EE.SE have the equipment or knowledge to do that.

Comment: Do you see a case where a commercially available and undamaged supply would say "isolated" according the multimeter test, but not actually be isolated?  I don't, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @DavidKessner The question does not suggest that it was undamaged, designed correctly, passes the regs or that the data sheets are available. Given also that the question mentions no earth connection and CE regs, it is almost certain that the OP is talking about safety and not just galvanic isolation.

Comment: Yes, I know that the OP didn't suggest that.  But I am asking that, for my own curiosity.  I'm not debating you, I am wondering if I actually missed something.

Comment: I can imagine a circuit for a non-galvanically isolated SMPS that would need the meter ohms measurement to overcome 2 x diode drops to register a reading. It's hypothetical of course. Input bridge rectifier and output bridge rectifier with secondary winding connected to neutral. I can't imagine such a thing exists. I guess anything with diodes/semis in could fool the meter if it couldn't overcome a certain forward voltage.